# I can't edit CSS with Inspect Element in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

I used to rely on Google Chrome ***Inspect Element** → Resources Tab → Stylesheets* feature where I would double click anywhere in the css source and I could edit it with live rendering in the page. 
It doesn't seem to work anymore and that makes me sad.
(I can do the same thing from the 'Sources' tab, but this requires more clicks)

I run Chrome v 21.0.1180.49 beta on OS X 10.6.8

PS. I found somebody else that [has the same issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/COJRjmq3bCY).

Comment: whelp.. ok, so Chrome is now dead.. where do we move to now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that for Chrome 21, live css editing has been moved to the 'Sources' tab. Huge relief that the functionality is still there!

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-bugs/mvGOga4O4HM

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking everywhere for a solution to this problem.

Comment: But how to edit <style> css ?